# Como utilizar Promise no Firebase Query?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Preciso fazer promises básicas como por exemplo essa:

1) Irá fazer uma query no Firebase, checando se existe uma determinada ID.
Caso exista esta ID, ele vai dar o .then dizendo que está ok e fazer algo, caso não irá dar o .catch, informando o problema.

**O que eu tentei fazer foi o seguinte:
Porém acho que não fiz do jeito correto.**

```
 this.queryMAP = () => {
        //let userId = this.getDBSReference().currentUser.uid;
        let mapRef = this.getDBSReference().ref('users/Aliansce/LOCATIONS/').orderByKey().equalTo('map1');
        mapRef.on('child_added', (snap) => {
            console.log(snap.key)
            snap.key.this.createPromise()
    });

    this.createPromise = () => {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(snap.key)
            if(snap.key == "map1"){
                resolve("igual")
            } else {
                reject("diferente");
            }
        }).then((sucess) =>{
            console.info("ae");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.warn("error")
        });
    };
```

Comment: Eu acho que `.orderByKey().equalTo('map1')` não é a sintaxe correcta não cara. Mas pelo que eu percebi você quer encontrar o objecto com a key `map1`. Vou postar a minha resposta agora

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu percebi, você quer uma localização através da sua key (id). Eu sugiro que você utilize a função `once()`. De acordo com a [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=pt-br#read_data_once) o `once()` retorna uma Promise.

Então você faria:

```
this.queryMAP = () => {
        //let userId = this.getDBSReference().currentUser.uid;
        let mapRef = this.getDBSReference().ref('users/Aliansce/LOCATIONS/').child('map1');
        mapRef.once('value').then((snap) =>{
            console.log(snap.key);
            console.info("ae");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.warn("error");
        });
    };
```